# Holy Spirit in apostles before Pentecost

Tags: gospels, pneumatology

Some say apostles got Holy Spirit on the day of Pentecost. I also think this is true in some way, but in gospels there is record that Jesus 'gave them authority over devils and diseases and sent them to preach gospel, to heal the sick, cleanse the lepers, raise the dead. etc.'. If they got it at Pentecost, with what power then did the twelve these wonders if not with Holy Spirit? Again Jesus in John 15 talks about Spirit that he will send it, does this mean they yet had no Spirit upon them?

Could it mean that apostles had just some spiritual gifts like healing before Pentecost, but after it they received gift of prophesy and gift of tongues? Or is this authority that I mentioned just about Jesus' own power he gave them and isn't about Spirit in themselves like when he said to Peter to cast net into water and pulled out much fishes?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please take the Tour, see below, where you will find that in order to practice biblical hermeneutics we need a text upon which to practice the technique. But we do not debate and discuss biblical topics. You may find that without a specific text of scripture your question could be voted for closure as 'off-topic'

Answer (score 2):

Not only apostles, but even the prophets of the Old Testament, who are lower than apostles, had a degree of presence of Spirit in themselves, through Whom they prophesied (needn't to give references, for they are so numerous!).

In the New Testament, Elisabeth, John the Forerunner's mother, was filled with Spirit as she saw the pregnant Virgin, and she prophesied immediately (Luke 1:39-41) and so did the old widow-prophetess Anna at vision of Jesus taken to the temple (Luke 2:36-38); John the Forerunner himself was filled with Holy Spirit from his childhood (Luke 1:15), and of course the apostles, even before the Pentecost, had a degree of presence of Spirit in them (at least no less than John the Forerunner), through which presence they could act miracles; they got even to a greater degree of intensity the gift of the Spirit, when Jesus - before the Pentecost - blew in them the Spirit and added to them (through this new dimension of the presence of Spirit) an ability to forgive sins (John 20:22).

Thus, the Pentecost is the culmination, the ultimate gift of Spirit, when the apostles get Him to such an extent and intensity that they can already be emboldened by Him to preach to all corners of the world, withstanding all calamities and opposing powers. However, of course, the apostles had smack of the Spirit even before, for even before Spirit was present in them to a certain degree and intensity; they possessed the Spirit-ual gifts even before the Pentecost, however the gifts of the Infinite Spirit are also infinite and at the Pentecost they got a greater share of this graceful infinity, so as to totally be absorbed in it.

Answer (score 1):

The indwelling Holy Spirit was only sent after Jesus' resurrection.

> John 7:37 On the last and greatest day of the festival, Jesus stood and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink. 38Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them.” 39By this he meant the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were later to receive. Up to that time the Spirit had not been given, since Jesus had not yet been glorified.

> John 16:7 But very truly I tell you, it is for your good that I am going away. Unless I go away, the Advocate will not come to you; but if I go, I will send him to you.

> Luke 24:49 I am going to send you what my Father has promised; but stay in the city until you have been clothed with power from on high.

> Acts 2
> 1 When the day of Pentecost came, they were all together in one place. 2Suddenly a sound like the blowing of a violent wind came from heaven and filled the whole house where they were sitting. 3They saw what seemed to be tongues of fire that separated and came to rest on each of them. 4All of them were filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues a as the Spirit enabled them.

The indwelling Spirit permanently dwells in the believer. Before that from the OT time onward, the Holy Spirit would come on a person and it is not permanent.

> 1 Samuel 11:6 When Saul heard their words, the Spirit of God came powerfully upon him, and he burned with anger.

> 1 Samuel 16:14
> Now the Spirit of the LORD had departed from Saul, and an evil spirit from the LORD tormented him.

The NT first Pentecost was the demarcation point when the Holy Spirit first indwelled people. Before that the Holy Spirit came on people for specific gifts and purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different kinds of spirit:

- A life spirit that forms the life-force of all living creatures.
- A human spirit that distinguishes humans from other animals.
- An ad hoc spirit that, perhaps temporarily, allows direct communication with God.
- A holy spirit that combines with the human spirit to create the embryo of a new spirit being.

What was received at Pentecost was the holy spirit that as of that day was offered to all mankind.
It was not the same as the ad hoc spirit that was previously given to the Apostles, Israelite prophets, etc.

See my answer to [hermeneutical approaches - How do we reconcile 2 Corinthians 6:16 with 1 Corinthians 3:16-17?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77159/how-do-we-reconcile-2-corinthians-616-with-1-corinthians-316-17/77166#77166).

Answer (score -1):

In the Old Testament, God dwelled in the Holy Temple, but when Jesus died on the cross the curtain of the Temple was torn in two from top to bottom (Mark 15:38-39, and God no longer dwelled in the Temple, for now Jesus is our new foundation and cornerstone. Our bodies are the NEW temple. The Holy Spirit dwells within a believer that has truly repented. For as long as the person is faithful, the Holy Spirit will remain forever.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).